# Can "NOT EXISTS" replace "NOT IN" by only swapping the sentences?

Tags: db2, db2-400

How would I make NOT EXISTS work here when it works correctly with NOT IN and I should be getting the same results using NOT EXISTS but I am not.

What is wrong with my logic in using the NOT EXISTS sentence

The NOT EXISTS should be comparing to A.C_SEQUENCE like the NOT IN. Same logic as the NOT IN which gives me the correct records.

```
Select A.C_SEQUENCE, A.STATUS 
FROM PROD.CONTROL A
where A.AID = 'BILLINGS'
and A.USER='GLOBAL_NETWORK'
--and A.STATUS = 'ON'
and NOT EXISTS
(
        select B.H_SEQUENCE
        from PROD.STATUS_R B, PROD.CONTROL A
        where A.USER='GLOBALNETWORK'
        and A.C_SEQUENCE = B.H_SEQUENCE 
        and B.H_STAT in('IGN','ACK')
)
order by C_date DESC limit 5000
```

---

```
Select A.C_SEQUENCE, A.STATUS 
FROM PROD.CONTROL A
where A.AID = 'BILLINGS'
and A.USER='GLOBAL_NETWORK'
--and A.STATUS = 'ON'
and A.C_SEQUENCE NOT IN 
(
        select B.H_SEQUENCE
        from PROD.STATUS_R B, PROD.CONTROL A
        where A.USER='GLOBALNETWORK'
        and A.C_SEQUENCE = B.H_SEQUENCE 
        and B.H_STAT in('IGN','ACK')
)
order by C_date DESC limit 5000
```

Comment: I suspect you don't really want `, PROD.CONTROL A` in the correlated subquery in either case.

Comment: Please provide sample data with expected and actual results.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks, your comment solved this issue by removing the PROD.CONTROL A the query ran perfectly. Now I don't understand why?

Comment: You need to correlate what you select from PROD.STATUS_R to the specific record in the outer query from PROD.CONTROL. Instead you are providing a separate instance of PROD.CONTROL inside the subselect, with the same correlation name A to confuse things even more. As a result the subselect is not correlated to the outer select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sample data, this is just a shot in the dark, but I would write the `NOT EXISTS` version this way:

```
Select A.C_SEQUENCE, A.STATUS 
FROM PROD.CONTROL A
where A.AID = 'BILLINGS'
and A.USER='GLOBAL_NETWORK'
--and A.STATUS = 'ON'
and NOT EXISTS
(
        select *
        from PROD.STATUS_R B
        and A.C_SEQUENCE = B.H_SEQUENCE 
        and B.H_STAT in('IGN','ACK')
)
order by C_date DESC limit 5000
```

`NOT EXISTS` means that you only want outer select records where the sub-select does not return a record. But really, since the sub-select does not include much that is not already in the outer select, It might perform better to write this thing like this:

```
Select A.C_SEQUENCE, A.STATUS 
FROM PROD.CONTROL A
  left exception join prod.status_r_b b
    on b.h_sequence = a.c_sequence
      and b.h_stat in ('IGN', 'ACK')
where A.AID = 'BILLINGS'
  and A.USER='GLOBAL_NETWORK'
--and A.STATUS = 'ON'
order by C_date DESC limit 5000
```

You should also be able to simplify the `NOT IN` version like this:

```
Select A.C_SEQUENCE, A.STATUS 
FROM PROD.CONTROL A
where A.AID = 'BILLINGS'
and A.USER='GLOBAL_NETWORK'
--and A.STATUS = 'ON'
and A.C_SEQUENCE NOT IN 
(
        select B.H_SEQUENCE
        from PROD.STATUS_R B
        and B.H_STAT in('IGN','ACK')
)
order by C_date DESC limit 5000
```

In this case `NOT IN` acknowledges that rows could be returned, but you are only going to select rows from `prod.control` where the sequence number is not in the filtered `prod.status_r` result set.